# mysql , запрос данных с условием сортировки

Tags: c#, mysql

есть 2 таблицы с данными. в обоих таблицах существует столбец c похожими данными. ниже выложил код и изображение. чтоб понятно было

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        var command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       
        command.CommandText = " SELECT dslam FROM dslamSum WHERE sats ='" + SatsCombobox + "'";

        var adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        var dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dslamcomboBox.Items.Add(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
            con.Close();

        }
    
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при выборе значения SatsCombobox хочу вывести dslamcomboBox только те строки где совпадают данные столбца sats.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот код не работает?

Comment: не работает в том плане что сравнение не идет

Comment: может запрос не правильный ?

Comment: Как вы это поняли? Почему у вас опять конкатенация строк в запросе? Вроде же недавно нормально делали.

Comment: запросы добавлением данных оформлены через Parametrs.   тут я для практики отдельно тренируюсь , если получится занесу в основной проект.  через SATS (SatsCombobox ) коллекции выбираю один элемент но в нижний combobox ничего не выводится , полагаю сравнение не сработал

Comment: можете помочь с этим вопросом ?

Comment: Отладка, пошаговое выполнение кода, проверка значений переменных - знакомый процесс?

Comment: "SELECT dslam FROM dslamSum WHERE sats ='" + SatsCombobox + "'" "SELECT dslam FROM dslamSum WHERE sats ='System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 23'" чтоб могло значит ?

Comment: `SatsCombobox` - это контрол, вы его подставили в строку. Вот он и вписался как строка. Вы опять совершаете ту же ошибку, которую я вам исправил в прошлом вопросе.

Comment: я пробовал SatsCombobox.SelectedIndex, SatsCombobox.Text, все равно ничего не помогает , как будто запрос не видит коллекцию  SatsCombobox

Comment: `command.CommandText = " SELECT dslam FROM dslamSum WHERE sats = sats 6/0";`     если конкретно сравнивать то выводит с сравнением.